# How does one devise a Grover quantum oracle despite the no-cloning theorem?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

I think I have misunderstood Grover's quantum search algorithm, and would appreciate clarification.

From what I understand, the Oracle operator takes an index register of qubits $|x\rangle$ (that will later be measured to find the solution) and a function $f(x)$ where $f(x) = 1$ for the correct solution $x$ such that
$$
|x\rangle \xrightarrow{\textrm{Oracle}} (-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle
$$

Nielsen and Chaung's text has the idea of setting aside qubits as an *Oracle workspace* to provide extra room for the computing of $f(x)$. In addition, the above statement suggests that the Oracle must keep $|x\rangle$ "intact" with the exception of inverting the sign of the correct answer.

Without a Oracle workspace, I imagine that the Oracle operator would transform $|x\rangle$ into $|f(x)\rangle$ (but reversibly so, of course). Unless I've misunderstood, this is undesirable because we wish to measure $x$.

How does one use the Oracle workspace? As I understand it, the no-cloning theorem means that one cannot copy qubits in and out from the $|x\rangle$ register and the Oracle workspace, so what operations are done in the workspace?

Comment: Transforming $|x\rangle$ to $|f(x)\rangle$ is not reversible. Such oracle could be applied only once, since the input $x$ is lost after the first application.  The oracle workspace is used in the following sense: $|x\rangle|0\rangle \xrightarrow{\textrm{Oracle}} (-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle|0\rangle$. The extra $|0\rangle$ register is the workspace that starts in $|0\rangle$ and is returned in $|0\rangle$ and is used to reversibly compute $f(x)$ (i.e., compute $f(x)$, apply it as a phase of the first register and then uncompute).

Comment: Also note that such a "phase" oracle can be implemented given an oracle which computes $\lvert x\rangle\lvert y\rangle \lvert 0 \rangle \rightarrow \lvert x\rangle\lvert y\oplus f(x)\rangle \lvert 0 \rangle$, which corresponds to a classical circuit.

Comment: I might be thinking about the oracle in the wrong way, but how does one "move" the $x$ information to the $|y\rangle$ qubits? Is it a string of CNOT gates, or something else?

Comment: Once you have computed $f(x)$ in some qubit, you can indeed copy it to $y$ using a CNOT gate. How to compute any function without leaving any traces (except storing $f(x)$ in the $y$ register) is shown in [C. H. Bennett, IBM Journal of Research and Development 17, 525 (1973)](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall04/cos576/papers/bennett73.html).